# Permission denied metricbeat on openshift

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, metricbeat

I'm trying to deploy metricbeat on openshift, and after many hours of work i cannot have it worked. 
The same image is running normally on docker.
Thank you

```
#Dockerfile

FROM docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:7.2.0
COPY metricbeat.yml /usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml
USER root 
RUN mkdir /var/log/metricbeat \
    && chown metricbeat /usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml \
    && chown metricbeat /usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat \
    && chmod go-w /usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml \
    && chown metricbeat /var/log/metricbeat

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint \
    && chown metricbeat /usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint

ENV PATH="/usr/share/metricbeat:${PATH}"

USER metricbeat

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint" ]

#entrypoint.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat -e --strict.perms=false -c /usr/share    /metricbeat/metricbeat.yml
```

Error: /usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint: line 2: /usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat: Permission denied

Comment: Can you check what exact permission that file has got `docker run -it --rm image-name /bin/sh` and then `ls -ltrh /usr/share/metricbeat/`

Comment: This is the result : -rwxr-x---

Comment: The image is designed to run as `root`, but OpenShift will run as an assigned user ID different to `root`. You need to design your image to handle that, or relax the security policy of OpenShift. https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-can-i-enable-an-image-to-run-as-a-set-user-id.html

Comment: Thank you @mchawre , i'll try to build the whole project so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dockerfile shows switching to the `root` user while setting up the directory structure and permissions when building the image, and finally switching to `USER metricbeat` to run the container with it.

However, by default OpenShift runs containers with a user with a random UID (from a preconfigured range).

One option is to relax the security policy as Graham Dumpleton suggested.

To make it work without relaxing the security, I'll suggest to change ownership as follows:

```
RUN chown -R metricbeat:root /usr/share/metricbeat \
 && chmod -R 0775 /usr/share/metricbeat
```

...or incorporate the above two commands in the first `RUN` instruction.